# graphql-java-servlet's removal of SimpleGraphQLServlet

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

In an old version of graphql-java-servlet I used to extend SimpleGraphQLServlet and then override GraphQLContext createContext( Optional request, Optional response ) to add a cookie to the response. I would also override GraphQLErrorHandler getGraphQLErrorHandler() to do some custom error handling.

I'm now trying to do a large jump in version to graphql-java-servlet 6.x.
As of graphql-java-servlet 6.x, SimpleGraphQLServlet is gone. There now is a SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet, which I can't use directly.

Unfortunately, though, the github documentation is way out of date and still suggests using SimpleGraphQLServlet even though it is long gone. There are some builders and I can find some very simplistic references outside of the github documentation, but none of them cover my use cases.

I don't want to do anything fancy, but I need to be able to add a cookie to the response and do some custom error handling.

How can I do this in graphql-java-servlet 6.x? I can't seem to find any clarity on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is [GraphQLServletListener](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/graphql/servlet/GraphQLServletListener.java). It is also described in [project docs](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet/tree/master#servlet-listeners), although it is a bit  wrong (no `OperationCallback` in code).

Anyway, here is a working piece of code (used `com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-java-servlet:6.1.4`):

```
    GraphQLSchema schema = getSchema();
    List<GraphQLServletListener> listeners = new ArrayList<GraphQLServletListener>();
    GraphQLServletListener lstnr = new GraphQLServletListener(){

        public RequestCallback onRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
            System.out.println("onRequest:" + request.getRequestURI());
            //TODO cookies here
            response.addCookie(new Cookie("sample","test"));

            return new RequestCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess:" + request.getRequestURI());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Throwable throwable) {
                    //TODO add some error handling here
                    System.out.println("onError:" + request.getRequestURI());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinally(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
                    System.out.println("onFinally:" + request.getRequestURI());
                }

            };
        }
    };
    listeners.add(lstnr);

    SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet servlet = SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet.newBuilder(schema)
        .withListeners(listeners)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks @Eugene. This gets me part of the way there, but there is a problem. I need to be able to create the cookie in my resolver. So when I mentioned that I overwrote createContext, what I meant is this: 1. I overwrote createContext to return a wrapper which included an addCookie method. 2. In my resolver, I got the context from the data fetching environment and added the cookie.  They appear to have also changed the way the GraphQLContext class works. So I'm not sure if this is still feasible? Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like perhaps I can do the override by customizing GraphQLContextBuilder, but then how do I tie that in to this servlet?

Comment: @MarkNenadov what is the resolver that are you talking about? Besides, I think you struggling with graphql-servlet more than it helps you. Maybe you should implement your own servlet for graphql and get rid of graphql-servlet ?

Comment: The resolver I'm talking about is a custom resolver used to handle a graphql query. I'm not sure how what you propose here would help--implementing my own servlet for graphql would still leave me without the functionality I need *in my resolvers*. It is possible I am missing something, though. That said, I got in touch with a graphql-java-servlet developer and it seems in their refactoring they inadvertently dropped the response object from their context builder. So my answer turns out to be to wait for the next release, which will include it and should allow me to do what I need to do.

Comment: @MarkNenadov Can you please guide on how to wrap errors in SimpleGraphqlHttpServlet using GraphQLErrorHandler. Currently, I am only getting InternalServer error in the response and I am stuck with this for a couple of days.